# How to separte the value in array_intersect in php

Tags: php

Based on the user selection  I want to show the form elements.Here the user selects class1,class6,engg.how do I bring the all form element in one common form  right know I am having different form for class 1,6,8 and many more.if user selected the all three classes(1,6,8), class 1 has differnet subject,like wise class 6 is different subject and engg has differen subject.Now I want to show all form elements under one form based one user selections. it user wish.user select class1 means i have to show class1 form.  so far I have done. my htmlform,my phpvalues, I have used  array_intersect.now many problem is if user picks class(1,6,8) How do I bring all the form element under one form and has one submit button.

```
  <form name="frm" method="post">
        <table align="center">
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txt" id="txt" required ></td><td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" required></td><td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Product</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="class1">class1
                    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="class6">class6
                    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="class8">class8
                    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="class10">class10
                    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="class12">class12
                    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="engineering">engineering
                    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="technology">technology
                </td><td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save"></td><td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
My PHP VALUES
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $name    = $_POST['txt'];
    $pass    = $_POST['pass'];
    $product = $_POST['chk'];
$class1SubjectFormValues = array('class1', 'class6', 'class8', ... );
$class12SubjectFormValues = array('class10', 'class12', 'class8','eng' );

if (array_intersect($product, $class1SubjectFormValues)) {
    // class1 subject form
}
if (array_intersect($product, $class12SubjectFormValues)) {
    // class12 subject form
}
?>
**Here is my class1 form**
<p>class1 subject form</p>
<form name="f1" action="" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="allsubject">allsubject
        <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="science">science
        <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="maths">maths
</form>
</p>

**Here is my class6 form**
<p>class1 subject form</p>
<form name="f1" action="" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="allsubject">allsubject
        <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="science">science
        <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="maths">maths
    <input type="text" name="name" value="">Tutor Name
       <input type="text" name="name" value="">Tutor Address
</form>
</p>
**Here is my engg form**
    <p>class1 subject form</p>
    <form name="f1" action="" method="post">
        <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="allsubject">csc
            <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="science">IT
            <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="maths">maths
        <input type="text" name="name" value="">Tutor Name
           <input type="text" name="name" value="">Tutor Address
    </form>
    </p>
```

I Want  output like this:

```
<form name="f1" action="" method="post">
<p>class1
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="allsubject">allsubject
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="science">science
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="maths">maths
</p>
<p>class6
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="allsubject">allsubject
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="science">science
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="maths">maths
<input type="text" name="name" value="">Tutor Name
<input type="text" name="name" value="">Tutor Address
</p>
<p>class  8</p>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="allsubject">csc
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="science">IT
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="maths">maths
<input type="text" name="name" value="">Tutor Name
<input type="text" name="name" value="">Tutor Address
<input type="submit">
</form>
```